# Flask Gunicorn can't find application

Tags: python, heroku, gunicorn

I'm creating an application using Flask. Everything works fine when running it with directly with Python, but I want to host it on Heroku, so I need to figure out how to use Gunicorn. The problem I'm having is that since `app.py` isn't in my root folder, it can't be run by simply typing `gunicorn app` or something like that. My folder structure is the following:

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── myproject
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── static
│   └── templates
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
```

where `app.py` looks something like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I have tried using Gunicorn to run it in the following ways...

`gunicorn myproject app.py`

`gunicorn myproject app:app`

`gunicorn myproject/app.py`

I have also tried creating an `__init__.py` in `myproject/`, but I have no idea what to put in there to make this work.

Comment: `myproject.app`. You'll need an `__init__.py` in the my project directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding to `__init__.py` the wsgi instance that you want to export.

`from .app import app`

This way the wsgi `app` is available when importing `myproject` and you should be able to run your app with `gunicorn myproject:app`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late response but I have run in to this issue deploying a flask app.  It seems to be intermittent.

My issue is that even though I'm in my venv gunicorn from the command line seems to be ignoring the venv however if I run gunicorn with the full path in the venv it works

```
which gunicorn
```

> /home/ubuntu/FieldWorker/venv/bin/gunicorn

```
/home/ubuntu/FieldWorker/venv/bin/gunicorn
# correctly outputs
```

> [2022-01-10 23:15:52 +0000] [1280] [INFO] Starting
> gunicorn 20.1.0 [2022-01-10 23:15:52 +0000] [1280] [INFO] Listening
> at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1280) [2022-01-10 23:15:52 +0000] [1280]
> [INFO] Using worker: sync [2022-01-10 23:15:52 +0000] [1282] [INFO]
> Booting worker with pid: 1282 [2022-01-10 23:15:52 +0000] [1283]
> [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1283 DEBUG:ngoupdate:ngoupdate.py

Whereas

```
gunicorn
```

> gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 'fieldworker:create_app()' [2022-01-10
> 23:15:26 +0000] [1275] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4 [2022-01-10
> 23:15:26 +0000] [1275] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1275)
> [2022-01-10 23:15:26 +0000] [1275] [INFO] Using worker: sync
> [2022-01-10 23:15:26 +0000] [1277] [INFO] Booting worker with pid:
> 1277 [2022-01-10 23:15:26 +0000] [1277] [ERROR] **Exception in worker**
> process ... ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

(venv) ubuntu@ip-172-31-1-144:~/prod$ which python3
/home/ubuntu/FieldWorker/venv/bin/python3